# Email notification about new files on Azure File share

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, azure-logic-apps, azure-files

What are possible ways to implement such scenario?
I can think of some Azure function which will periodically check the share for new files. Are there any other possibilities.

I have been thinking also about duplicating the files to Blob storage and generate the notifications from there.

Comment: Who is putting the file into the file share? Potentially an option could be to create an API that takes a file and uploads it to the file share as well as triggering an email notification.

Comment: Changing the writer or the file share is not an option. There is no possibility to hook in current pipeline. The solution must be independent.

Comment: if you can use blob storage you can utilize the azure logic app service it has built in connectors using them you can create a work flows . for your scenario you can use  trigger `When blob is added or modified` to monitor your storage account container & at the end of the logic app workflow you can add Outlook connect to send the details of that blob when this workflow got triggered.

Comment: if you are looking for a solution in azure functions , you can create [azure blob trigger function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-trigger?tabs=csharp) in that you will specify the path for the function to  monitor. if any new blob got added to the path the function will get triggered

Comment: It is maybe not clear but I have "fixed" fileshare(Its content is also shared via SFTP). I maybe can somehow duplicate to blobstorage and then use your recommendation. But so far I am not clear how to duplicate the content to blob storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Storage content trigger is by default available for `blobs`. If you look for migrating to blob storage, then you can utilise `BlobTrigger` Azure function. In case of file trigger in File Share, the below are my suggestions as requested:

- A `TimerTrigger` Azure function that acts as a poll to check for new file in that time frame the previous trigger occured.
- Recurrence trigger in logic app to poll and check for new contents.
- A `continuous WebJob` to continuously poll the File Share checking for new contents.

In my opinion, duplicating the files to Blob storage and making your notification work may not be a great option, because such operation once again requires a polling mechanism which can be achieved with options like a few mentioned above, but is still unnecessary.